# Hibernate Formula prefix

Tags: hibernate, mariadb

I need to select a property from an mariadb dynamic column with hibernate.

Therefore I am using the `@Formula` annotation with `COLUMN_GET`

```
@Formula("COLUMN_GET(variable_data, 'mileage' AS INTEGER)")
Integer mileage
```

But for some reason Hibernate inserts the table alias before `INTEGER` and the sql query fails.

A workaround is to use `DOUBLE(10,0)`. This way Hibernate does not interpret this as a variable and the query is ok.

I tried to implement a Hibernate UserType but I can not manipulate the select attributes with this mechanism.

Are there any other ways to go?

Comment: Sigh.  The problems that 3rd party software adds.

Comment: Very helpful comment!

Comment: Hello. Did you found any solution?